# Does function offset inside a module remain the same always?

Tags: memory

I have an executable (say notepad.exe). I am trying to create a function map for this executable. So when I run this executable it gets loaded in some address (base address of module). Now each function will have some offset inside the module. I try and uniquely identify each function by their offset (where the code of a function starts) inside the module. Do you think this offset will always remain the same, no matter on which machine I run the executable?

Comment: It's not clear to me what loads what. Please, clarify. Besides that, what's the end goal?

Comment: @jweyrich: I meant the process is loaded inside the memory. I don't really know who loads it. the end goal is to uniquely identify each function inside a program by its offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has had, since Vista, a feature known as address-space layout randomization, where the base of executables is placed at random start addresses. The goal is to thwart certain kinds of security attacks. Right now, no internal randomization of functions takes place, but there is nothing preventing that from happening in a new version of Windows.

Comment: I know about ASLR but I thought it was done only for the loaded dll's not for executables. Moreover, I observed the base of my executable to be the same even if I run it on different machines. So, according to you the offset should remain the same, right?

Comment: @Bruce: right, the offsets should remain the same. Microsoft uses a tool to optimize the layout of basic blocks in their executables (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/cse/bit_projects.mspx); this is fundamentally at odds with function re-ordering / randomization, so I would expect it to be a safe assumption for now that function offsets are immutable.